# How to move a cube on a plane

Tags: mesh, objects, faces, 3d-cursor, origin

I'm using blender 2.8 and my simple scenario is: a plane and a cube mesh.

I want to move the cube on the plane without using the `G` command on the `Z` axis of the cube mesh, because doing *freehand* it's not perfect.

What's the best practice using blender tools?

Thanks

Comment: if you place your cube on the right Z location, then you can move it with shift Z so that it doesn't move anymore on the Z axis, you can also lock its location on the Z axis on the 3D view N panel, or even give it a Limit Location constraint...

Comment: I have used the snap tool, and does what I needed. Thanks @moonboots for your help, I've learned that I can do the same thing in many different ways.

Comment: yes of course, snap tool as well  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Helpful tricks to use when moving/scaling/rotating an object: to move on two axes while scaling/moving/rotating press S/G/R then SHFT+(axis you don't want to transform on). This will allow you to move on, say both X+Y axes, but not the Z axis if you press G-SHFT+Z, or only scale on X and Z- S-SHFT+Y.

Comment: And if you want to make a lot of movements, you can position view perpendicularly to the surface you want to move on. E.g. Numpad 7 for top orthogonal view to move only on XY plane, without the need to press SHIFT + Z each time.